# SoapClient fails to load WSDL where SoapUI has no issue

Tags: php, soap-client, ssh-tunnel

At my office I can connect directly to the relevant soap servers and my code works as it should.
However - because of security - it is not allowed that VPN connections (from home) access the SOAP servers. So I have to resort to using an SSH tunnel over a jump-station.

Because the WSDL files contain absolute urls I can't use the "location" to change this, it won't load the WSDL. Therefor I've resolved to adding entries to the hosts files mapping that server name to 127.0.0.1 and and SSH tunnel to our jumpstation forwarding the correct ports.

This allows me to use the original WSDL without modification. I just have to comment out the hosts entries when at the office.

Via SoapUI everything works. I can load the WSDL, it fully parses it (it has a lot of includes - big corporate soap service) and I can launch SOAP requests that get answered correctly.

However, if I do the same via the php SoapClient (running against an apache on localhost) it throws an exception:
`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://wsdl.service.addres:port/wsdlUri?SCHEMA%2Fsoa.osb.model%2Fsrc%...'`
(I've replaced the server and the rest of the request because its not relevant.)

If I take that entire URL and paste it into my browser it results in an WSDL-XML.

The PHP code to load create the SoapClient is as simple as this:

```
$options =
[
   'trace' => 1,
   'exception' => 1,
];
$wsdl = '/path/to/local/wsdlfile.xml';
$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

Anyone have a clue where to look? I can't think of anything to try anymore. 
I know for sure that my PHP is setup correctly (as the code has been working for months at the office and nothing was changed here). Is PHP doing DNS resolving differently and somehow getting another (or no) IP for that corporate server perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get redirected if you paste this URL into your browser? So probably from `http` to `https`? Because if you get automatically redirected you have to take the final URL because `SoapClient` just receives the `302 Moved Permanentely` header for example and this is no valid `WSDL` file.

Comment: If it was (but it isn't) it wouldn't work directly from the office either. It's the same WSDL file.

Comment: Already compared a `traceroute` executed by yourself in the CL and a `traceroute` executed through PHP? Are they the same?

Comment: A traceroute does not say much as the hostname mentioned in the WSDL file is re-routed to localhost (but I've confirmed it in PHP and CLI just the same). Unless you connect to the specific tunnel-port you never leave the server.

Comment: If you grab the content of the WSDL url with something like CURL in PHP what's its content?

Comment: The WSDL file is locally cached, so that always loads, but it's a very good idea! I've just tried to do a php curl of the error mentioned in the exception (including query part and everything) and it outputs a perfect XML. So PHP can connect to the server and actually load that URL it throws on. Sigh.